# Not getting the output I need in my code and I can't figure out why. Python

Tags: python, for-loop, output

The exercise I'm working on is supposed to display the following output:

> ```
> Enter name of data file: gps.txt
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  Time     Latitude    Longitude       Distance        Pace
> (hh:mm:ss)    (deg)       (deg)       (miles)     (min/miles)
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 10:57:32   38.898556  -77.037852      *****       *****
> 11:00:45   38.897147  -77.043934      0.341       9.421
> 11:03:28   38.896432  -77.052102      0.442       6.141
> 11:05:34   38.897411  -77.047212      0.272       7.730
> 11:08:58   38.898999  -77.040000      0.403       8.431
> 11:13:54   38.909032  -77.036894      0.713       6.915
> 11:19:24   38.920011  -77.029782      0.850       6.471
> 11:25:47   38.931111  -77.025432      0.802       7.957
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Your fastest speed was 6 minutes and 9 seconds per mile.
> ```

When I run my program here is was gets outputted:

> ```
> Enter name of data file: gps.txt
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  Time     Latitude    Longitude      Distance      Pace
> (hh:mm:ss)    (deg)       (deg)       (miles)     (min/miles)
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 10:57:32   38.898556   -77.037852     *****       *****
> 11:00:45   38.897147  -77.043934      0.341       1935.282
> 11:03:28   38.896432  -77.052102      0.442       1500.225
> 11:05:34   38.897411  -77.047212      0.272       2449.924
> 11:08:58   38.898999  -77.040000      0.403       1658.896
> 11:13:54   38.909032  -77.036894      0.713       944.564
> 11:19:24   38.920011  -77.029782      0.850       799.326
> 11:25:47   38.931111  -77.025432      0.802       854.834
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Your fastest speed was 854
> ```

As you can see, almost everything is correct except for pace and for the fastest speed down at the bottom. The file I am reading out of looks like this:

> ```
> 10:57:32 38.898556 -77.037852 
> 11:00:45 38.897147 -77.043934 
> 11:03:28 38.896432 -77.052102 
> 11:05:34 38.897411 -77.047212 
> 11:08:58 38.898999 -77.040000 
> 11:13:54 38.909032 -77.036894 
> 11:19:24 38.920011 -77.029782 
> 11:25:47 38.931111 -77.025432
> ```

Comment: i think the line this_pace = time_elapsed is supposed to be time/distance

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that you've set "this_pace" to "time elapsed", without bothering to incorporate the distance in your calculation.

In the future, add tracing print statements to trace both execution flow and the data computed.  For instance, printing and checking each variable in your main calculation loop, would have shown the problem line immediately.

Also, consider incremental development: add a few lines or one loop at a time.  Debug that before you add more.

Comment: He's incorporating the distance in the calculation of `time_elapsed`. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can also see that:

```
    current_dist = float(current_time - previous_time)
    time_elapsed = abs(((current_dist - previous_dist)/ 60) / distance)
    this_pace = time_elapsed
```

Seems to me that the first two are backwards. The first calculates time elapsed. The second calculates pace; it should just calculate the distance, with the pace calculated on the this_pace line.